# How can I select three cadets for my team?

Tags: final-fantasy-type-0-hd

I am just starting out in Final Fantasy Type0 HD, and I have no idea how I can select three specific team members for my team?

So far I have tried in the 'Assignment' menu, but this just seems to set the main party member. Then in the reserve menu I can re-order my cadets, but in neither menu do I see a way to actually build a three cadet party.

How does the party system in Type0 HD work and how can I specify which cadets appear in my team during a battle or when exploring the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some testing in game for this and it seems that you only ever select your party leader using the 'Assignment' menu.

Then you have to order your reserves in the 'Reserves' menu to be in the order that you want to use them.

For example, I want a team consisting of Eight, King and Deuce. I need to set Eight as my active party leader and then ensure that both King and Deuce are in the two top spots of my reserve list.

Comment: This is true for walking around in the overworld. However, generally speaking, when you start a mission it will specifically ask you who you want in your reserves, and then from that list who is in you actual party. It asks for reserves first because you cannot take all 14 members on every mission.